# I need to perform a GET Request on a URL using python requests library and fetch only the last 100 lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, get, python-requests

Summary:
Currently i am doing a GET Request on a {.log} URL which is having around 7000+ lines. 
I need to GET the Response, validate for a particular message in the response and if its not present, i need to do a GET Request again on the same URL.
This iteration on the GET is very time consuming and most of the time results in a stuck state

Expectation:
I need a way out wherein i do a GET Request operation and fetch only last 100 lines as a response rather than fetching all the 7000+ lines every time.

URL = "http://sdd.log"

Code

```py
    def get_log(self):
        logging.info("Sending a get request to retrieve pronghorn log")
        resp = requests.request("GET", "http://ssdg.log")
        logging.info("Printing the callback url response")
        #logging.info(resp)
        #logging.info(resp.text)
        return resp.text
```

Comment: You may not be able to specify "get the last 100 lines" but you may if the server issues a `Accept-Ranges` response header, use the Range header. E.g., `Range: bytes=500-999`. You can issue a HEAD request to get the total size from the Content-Length response header[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving)

Comment: Apparently, you can use, e.g., `Range: bytes=-500` to get the last 500 bytes of the file so you won't need to know the length/size of the file beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply download only the last 100 lines of an HTTP request. You can however simply get the last 100 lines of the resulting response by using

```
data = resp.text.split('\n')
last_lines = '\n'.join(data[-100:])
return last_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if your server accepts range requests then you can use code like this to get the last 4096 bytes

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg'

resp = requests.request("HEAD", url)
unit = resp.headers['Accept-Ranges']
print(resp.headers['Content-Length'])
print(unit)
headers = {'Range': f'{unit}=-4096'}
print(headers)
resp = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
b = BytesIO()

for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
    b.write(chunk)

print(b.tell())

b.seek(0)
data = b.read()

print(f"len(data): {len(data)}")
```